# LG G Pad F7.0 WIFI can't see 5.0GHz

Tags: wi-fi

I recently purchased a 2018 Pacifica Hybrid with the U-Connect Theater system. This system allows mirror casting with compatible Android Devices. Miracast is available on my LG G Pad, but it can't see the car's WIFI network.

After some trial and error I realized that the on-car WIFI only puts out a 5.0GHz signal, and not a 2.4GHz.

I have a LG G Pad F7.0 that according to the specs is 802.11 b/g/n, so I should be able to access the 5.0GHz frequency. I've done some tests with various WIFI apps and it seems my unit can only see the 2.4GHz frequency currently.

In searching online I found that there should be a setting for WIFI which allows you to manually select 2.4 or 5.0, but my unit doesn't have this option in the menu. I am wondering if that has something to do with with the version of Lollipop installed?

So I guess my question is two-fold: Is there a way to enable 5.0GHz visibility with the 5.0.1 version my LG G Pad is running?

If not, would I be able to change android versions to see this frequency? Any recommendations/guidance here would help if this is my best bet.

Specs:
LG G Pad F7.0

Android 5.0.1

Kernel Version 3.10.49

Build Number LRX21Y

Software Version LK430ZV7

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

802.11 b/g/n - all those three modes are 2.4GHz only (802.11 n can theoretically also operate on 5GHz, however the number of devices that really support this seems to be very low).

Therefore your LG G Pad F7.0 does only support 2.4GHz Wifi. If the Wifi hotspot only operates on 5GHz you will never be able to use it by this device.

Only modes like 802.11a or 802.11ac indicate that 5GHz Wifi is supported.

Comment: I guess the lack of 802.11a means this is unfortunately the case.

802.11n can function on the 5.0GHz frequency, but I'm starting to think that it is only "optional" based on the manufacturer...?

Comment: For 5GHz you need a separate antenna. Therefore I assume that every device supporting 802.11n on 5GHz would also support 802.11a.